# How to cure kitten whose eye is closed and dripping with puss?

Tags: cats, health, eye-disease

The *feral kitten* at our home who *doesn't like to get picked up or held* and *runs away* when we try to do so *has hurt herself*. I don't know exactly what happened but I think that something pricked her eye or so. Initially **her eye had developed a red layer at side and it was bleeding**. Now it has converted into ***puss which keeps dripping and her eye is almost closed***. She is trying to open her eye but she's unable to do it. It's really hurting to see her in that condition but when I try to hold her to take her to vet she gets scared and runs away.

So the questions here are:

**i) Is it some medical condition that has caused her this red eye and puss or is it due to some accident?**

**ii) Is there any way I can try to cure it without holding her ( like putting some medicine in milk or something like that)**

**iii) If not, then how do I hold her to take it to vet ?**

Comment: take the kitten to the vet the vet needs to see the cat to treat her.if you dont have a carrier use a cardboard box with some holes in it so the cat gets air during transport.

Comment: @trondhansen , It doesn't come in hand like other cats. It gets sared and run away everytime I try to catch her to take her to vet.

Comment: sirai i have to asume you will be able to get hold of the cat in my comment if not there is little you can do.

Comment: You might be able to borrow an animal (cage) trap from a vet or animal charity, but @trondhansen is right, the kitten needs to be seen by a vet. The treatment will most likely be a topical antibiotic. The vet should know how to handle an uncooperative cat for treatment.